# How to grab next page url from pagination.

Tags: python, pagination, beautifulsoup

unable to fetch the url for next page. Throws traceback error. Basically i want to grab "/browse-movies?page=2"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
url = "https://yts.ag/browse-movies?page=1"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
items = soup.find_all('ul', 'tsc_pagination')[0]
for item in items:
    print item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urls = ["https://yts.ag/browse-movies?page={}".format(i) for i in range(1, 10)]  # make a url list and iterate over it
for url in urls:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   # your code here
        print year, rating, genre, title
```

Make a URL list and iterate over it. You can change the range.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `range(1, 300)` to iterate all pages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for i in range(1, 300):
    url = "https://yts.ag/browse-movies?page=%s" % i

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all('div', 'browse-movie-wrap')
    for item in items:
        for val in item.find_all('div','browse-movie-bottom'):
            title = item.find_all('a','browse-movie-title')[0].text
            year = item.find_all('div','browse-movie-year')[0].text
        for val in item.find_all('a','browse-movie-link'):
            try:
                rating = val.find_all('h4')[0].text
                genre = val.find_all('h4')[1].text 
            except:
                pass 

        print year, rating, genre, title
```

**P.S.** You might want to add `time.sleep(1)` to slow down a little bit in case they block your IP for being too aggressive scraping their webpages.

**Edit:**

Now look for the next page URL, you could use regular expression:

```
import re

next_page = soup.find('a', text=re.compile(r'.*Next.*'))
print next_page['href']
```

So what it does is to look for an `a` tag which has content matches regular expression `'.*Next.*'`.

Comment: Thanks Shane...it really worked but what if the url gonna be some random string everytime.

Comment: @ricky Then you might want to parse the page to get the new URL

Comment: Pardon me, I didn't quite get it. I am saying like I am parsing some page with url https://webpage/abc and let's say the next page would be https://webpage/xyz. How do I get this 'xyz' url while I am parsing the 'abc' webpage. Presuming there is only a next button on the 'abc' webpage......Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, it's like how you find those movies(year, rating etc) and you could also find/parse the link of next page, then use this link the next iteration and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Shane I have got it :) but I have found that on amazon underneath next button the url is like "href=/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahorse%2Bhead%2Bmask&page=2", there is no http:// thing in it, I mean it's not a complete url

Comment: @ricky Well that's a relative path, you just need to add a base URL in front of that path, which in your case I suppose it's `http://amazon.com`, the base URL should be the same with your current URL.

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't manage to grab next page url from current page, Can you please help me with that. I have just posted the code

Comment: @ricky: Just checked the webpage you mentioned, and still `page=` (1, 2, etc.) can be used to specify different pages, and just keep the rest url parameters and only change page number it still works.

Comment: Yes shane It's working(thanks to you) with page numbers but actually i was trying to get the next page url from pagination which i failed to fetch. Can you help me with. I just want to grab "/browse-movies?page=2" from pagination

Comment: @ricky Check my edit, you could use regular expression to look for next page tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot shane :)

Comment: I was actally trying to find <a> tag with class='current' and wanted to grab 'href' of next <a> tag element to it which is going to be url of next page. I was done grabbing "current class thing" but didn't know how to select "next element thing" from there

Comment: @ricky In that case, you could use `.next_sibling` to navigate to the next element, also `.previous_sibling` can be used to navigate to the previous one.